# Filter article that has featured image to shown on homepage

Tags: featured-post

How do I display article that has featured image uploaded?

I using premium theme. I found that all of the themes don't have this feature.

Am I need to configure this in php file?

Or there is another alternative way to fix this?

Hope this will not off topic.

[image]

I tried to add `'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'` in the script below, but not working.

```
        <div class="grids entries">

        <?php
        $cats_to_show = get_sub_field( 'category_posts_per_page');
        $cat_id = get_sub_field( 'category_section_name' );

        $ti_cat_posts = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'cat' => $cat_id,
                'no_found_rows' => true,
            )
        );
```

became

```
<div class="grids entries">

    <?php
    $cats_to_show = get_sub_field( 'category_posts_per_page');
    $cat_id = get_sub_field( 'category_section_name' );

    $ti_cat_posts = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'cat' => $cat_id,
            'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'  // Added 
            'no_found_rows' => true,
        )
    );
```

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have added the script and it was added in the post. But it not working. Is the array wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to limit the home page to display only posts that have a featured image, you'll need to modify the post query being used to generate that page.

With a premium theme it may be best to consult the theme's author first, to see if there is a configuration option or other easy method built-in to do what you want.

Otherwise, you may be able to create a child theme that modifies that query via a filter (perhaps using `has_post_thumbnail()`, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/) or much less desirably, by modifying the logic in the premium theme itself.

Comment: Please check my updated post. Can has_post_thumbnail() add directly in script?